# BPMN 2.0 -- How to represent a relational DB table in BPMN 2.0 format

Tags: bpmn

I am relatively new to BPMN 2.0 and dont carry much knowledge around the same. Can any of you help me in understanding that how to represent a relational database table in BPMN 2.0 format.

For example their is a master employee and employee salary table,how can i represent them in BPMN 2.0 format.

Regards
Manish

Comment: I am not sure why you need to do this. From my point of view, database and bpmn are used for different purpose. bpmn is used for workflow with events etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming to implement the [Relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) of a database, your choice is not the Business **Process** Model and Notation, but for instance [UML](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language). Even Camunda, a provider of BPMN-tools, uses UML for describing their internal database, see [their documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/database/).

**Disclosure:** I am not affiliated with Camunda, I just use their products a lot.